# Laravel 9: can't delete as super admin (spatie Laravel-permission)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-permission

I use Laravel 9 with Breeze and the package spatie Laravel-permission. I have created 2 roles and one of them is a super-admin role who should be able to do everything.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Implicitly grant "Super-Admin" role all permission checks using can()
       Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
        if ($user->hasRole('Super-Admin')) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

But when I tried to delete a row from my table "comments" using the CRUD than I had created: it doesn't seems to work (no error message or anything but nothing happen)

Blade where the button to delete is:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <tr>
            <td>"{{ $comment->com }}"</td>
            <br>

            @hasrole('user')
                USER
            @endhasrole

            @hasrole('Super-Admin')
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('comments.destroy',$comment->id)  }}">Delete</a>
            @endhasrole

           
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Route I use for the controlleur:

`Route::resource('comments', App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class);`

destroy function in controller:

```
public function destroy(Comment $Comment)
    {
        $Comment->delete();


        return redirect()->route('comments.index')
                        ->with('success','Comment deleted successfully');
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'com'
    ];
}
```

I dont think the problem come from Eloquent(ORM)  because when I use the all() function it seems to work like it should and the permissions seems to also be ok.

Comment: `dd($Comment);` showing what?

Comment: does comment model use softDeletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong endpoint. `href` attribute of `a` element sends the request using `GET` method. So you are not sending the request to `destroy` endpoint.

You need to use a form and pass the `@method` blade directive specifying `DELETE` method:

```php
<form action="{{ route('comments.destroy', $comment->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    @hasrole('Super-Admin')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    @endhasrole
</form>
```